# How to rotate a 3d cube in qml?

Tags: qt, 3d, qml

I am developing an application in Qt Creator with **QtQuick**. The purpose of this application is to rotate a cube in 3 dimensions with the help of a finger.

I managed to develop the creation of actions in relation to the finger movements but I am completely stuck on the rotation of the cube in relation to the fingers.

I have tried to create a direction vector with respect to the current and previous points as well as the normal vector. I have applied the Euler rotation in x and y on the cube but at a certain point, the cube does not rotate as expected.

Here is my qml code for the main page of the application :

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick3D 1.15
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import Qt3D.Extras 2.15

Window {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("MouseArea Demo")

        MouseArea{
            property int previousX: -1
            property int previousY: -1

            anchors.fill : parent

            onPressed: {

                previousX = mouseX;
                previousY = mouseY;
            }

            onPositionChanged: {

                let direction = Qt.vector2d(mouseX - previousX, mouseY - previousY).normalized();
                let normal = Qt.vector2d(direction.y, direction.x).normalized();
                console.log("direction : " + direction);
                console.log("normal : " + normal);
                cube.eulerRotation.x += normal.x * 3;
                cube.eulerRotation.y += normal.y * 3;



                previousX = mouseX;
                previousY = mouseY
            }

            onReleased: {

                previousX = -1;
                previousY = -1;

            }
        }

    View3D {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        camera: camera
        renderMode: View3D.Overlay


        PerspectiveCamera {
            id: camera
            position: Qt.vector3d(0, 200, 300)
            eulerRotation.x: -30

        }

        DirectionalLight {
            eulerRotation.x: -30
        }

        Model {

            id: cube
            visible: true
            position: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
            source: "#Cube"
            materials: [ DefaultMaterial {
                    diffuseMap: Texture {
                        id: texture
                        source: "../build-colorpicker2d-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/res.png"
                    }
                }
            ]                       
        }
    }

}
```

---

here is a video about what I talk to you 2 days ago about the y rotation problem.

Kind regards.

[image]

Comment: You have several options: rotating using quaternion - [Node.rotation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick3d-node.html#rotation-prop) which is preferable for me, and [Node.eulerRotation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick3d-node.html#eulerRotation-prop) but you have to remember that rotation order is important. Another important thing is origin point. In my application I manually calculate the angles and then place a shape using `rotation` and `position` i.e. place the shape with offset.

Comment: Is it important for you to use QtQuick3D? because you can use Qt3D classes instead of  QtQuick3D and there, these things that you want are so easy.

Comment: The cube is rotated according to `cube.eulerRotation`. The problem is that after a few clicks, the cube could be upside down and that means the Y axis will be inverted. And the problem is that dragging the mouse up and down will have the exact opposite effect on the cube. Not a trivial problem to solve with QtQuick3D so I second Parisa's answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your answer but I am new in 3d, I never do it in my university. Could you give me an example folibis please ?

Parisa,and karlphillip, I need to do it in qml with QtQuick it's for my internship

Comment: Ok, I write one example for you with qml , but I use Qt3d classes , I use scene3d and Entity instead of view 3d and model.

Comment: there is a difference between QtQuick and QtQuick3d.look at [this site](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html) . now in that example that I post I use qml and it is a QtQuick project but I use Qt 3D classes , these classes are much stable than  QtQuick3d classes look at [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick3d-index.html),I hope I could mean it

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should add this in your `.pro` file :

```
QT += qml quick 3dcore 3dinput 3dquick 3dlogic  3dquickextras  3dextras
```

I have 3 class in qml :**main.qml** , **RootEntity.qml** and **SOrbitCameraController.qml**

I have one Scene3D and inside this, I can put all my Entities. I Create a separate class and call it RootEntity.
The more important point of this way is orbitController that I use in my class. this makes that you can rotate cube by mouse and for doing this you need Entity. because of this, I use Scene3D and Entity instead of view3d and models.

In **main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

import "."

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Scene3D
    {
        id : scene3d
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        aspects: ["render", "logic", "input"]
        hoverEnabled: true
        cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio


        antialiasing: true

        RootEntity
        {
            id:root
        }

    }

}
```

in **RootEntity.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12
import Qt3D.Input 2.12

import "."


Entity {
    id: root

    //create camera

    Camera {
        id: mainCamera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: 16/9
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 4.49373, -3.78577)
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.5, 0.0)
    }

    //use my class instead of OrbitCameraController

    SOrbitCameraController {
        id: mainCameraController
        camera: mainCamera
    }

    components: [
        RenderSettings {

            Viewport {
                normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                RenderSurfaceSelector {
                    CameraSelector {
                        id: cameraSelector
                        camera: mainCamera
                        FrustumCulling {
                            ClearBuffers {
                                buffers: ClearBuffers.AllBuffers
                                clearColor: "#444449"
                                NoDraw {}
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.DiscardAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.AcceptAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                                ClearBuffers {
                                    buffers: ClearBuffers.DepthBuffer
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        InputSettings {}
        ,
        ScreenRayCaster
        {
            id:screenRayCaster
            onHitsChanged:
            {
                drawLineMesh(hits)

            }

        }
    ]

    Layer {
        id: topLayer
        recursive: true
    }


    Entity {
        id: cubeEntity
        components: [
            CuboidMesh
            {
                xExtent: 1
                yExtent: 1
                zExtent: 1


            }

            ,

            Transform {
                id: t
                translation: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)

            }
            ,
            PhongMaterial
            {
                ambient: "red"
            }


        ]

    }

}
```

in **SOrbitCameraController.qml** :

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0

Entity{
    id: root
    property Camera camera;
    property real dt: 0.001
    property real linearSpeed: 1
    property real lookSpeed: 500
    property real zoomLimit: 0.16

    MouseDevice {
        id: mouseDevice
        sensitivity: 0.001 // Make it more smooth
    }

    MouseHandler {
        id: mh
        readonly property vector3d upVect: Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0)
        property point lastPos;
        property real pan;
        property real tilt;
        sourceDevice: mouseDevice

        onPanChanged: root.camera.panAboutViewCenter(pan, upVect);
        onTiltChanged: root.camera.tiltAboutViewCenter(tilt);

        onPressed: {
            lastPos = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        }
        onPositionChanged: {
            // You can change the button as you like for rotation or translation
            if (mouse.buttons === 1){ // Left button for rotation
                pan = -(mouse.x - lastPos.x) * dt * lookSpeed;
                tilt = (mouse.y - lastPos.y) * dt * lookSpeed;
            } else if (mouse.buttons === 2) { // Right button for translate
                var rx = -(mouse.x - lastPos.x) * dt * linearSpeed;
                var ry = (mouse.y - lastPos.y) * dt * linearSpeed;
                camera.translate(Qt.vector3d(rx, ry, 0))
            } else if (mouse.buttons === 3) { // Left & Right button for zoom
                ry = (mouse.y - lastPos.y) * dt * linearSpeed
                zoom(ry)
            }

            lastPos = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)
        }
        onWheel: {
            zoom(wheel.angleDelta.y * dt * linearSpeed)
        }

        function zoom(ry) {
            if (ry > 0 && zoomDistance(camera.position, camera.viewCenter) < zoomLimit) {
                return
            }

            camera.translate(Qt.vector3d(0, 0, ry), Camera.DontTranslateViewCenter)
        }

        function zoomDistance(posFirst, posSecond) {
            return posSecond.minus(posFirst).length()
        }
    }
}
```

and at the end my **main.cpp** :

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication        app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine  engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

**the out put**
[image]

Comment: Hi Parisa, thank you so much for the exemple but I see that :  I noticed that when I rotate the cube downwards to turn it over completely, the finger movements to the left or right are reversed.
Can I fix it ?

Comment: I should check it, I don't have a touch divice for testing it, I do it by mouse. I didn't see that.

Comment: I send the bug I see about rotation in my last answer

Comment: Hi Parisa, how are you ?
If you want, I can give you my contact (email, skype, ... etc), it will be easier to communicate

Comment: I up the topic, the rotations are not fixed

Comment: @EtiennePERIANA, I show you what you need, what you say is another question.this is an example for rotate cube by mouse.

Comment: yes but you said, you will check what i show you the last time

Comment: I didn't find how should fix this bug

Comment: I try to make the rotations after checking camera y position, it works but some times the rotation don't work good

Comment: this is [Github repo](https://github.com/parisa-hr/SOrbitCameraController) , this bug relates to  SOrbitCameraController, I forked it from someone else . but as soon as I find it , I will fix it there and tell you too.

Answer (score 1):

The `Node` has a `rotate()` method. The trick is to do the rotation in `Node.SceneSpace`. This will ensure that the rotations compound correctly in any axis you choose in that the rotations will be applied on top of the latest orientation. I use a `MouseArea` to capture 2d movements in either X or Y. In 3d we interpret this as rotations in Y-axis or X-axis respectively. Here's a working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick3D
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    Node {
        id: standAloneScene
        DirectionalLight { ambientColor: Qt.rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) }
        Node {
            id: node
            Model {
                id: model
                source: "#Cube"
                materials: [
                    DefaultMaterial { diffuseColor: Qt.rgba(0.053, 0.130, 0.219, 0.75) }
                ]
            }
        }
        OrthographicCamera {
            id: cameraOrthographicFront
            y: 500; z: 1000
            lookAtNode: node
        }
    }
    View3D {
        anchors.fill: parent
        importScene: standAloneScene
        camera: cameraOrthographicFront
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill:parent
        property real pressedX
        property real pressedY
        onMouseXChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
        onMouseYChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
        onPressed: {
            [pressedX,pressedY] = [mouseX,mouseY];
        }
        function update() {
            let [dx,dy] = [mouseX - pressedX,mouseY - pressedY];
            [pressedX,pressedY] = [mouseX,mouseY];
            node.rotate(dx, Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0), Node.SceneSpace);
            node.rotate(dy, Qt.vector3d(1, 0, 0), Node.SceneSpace);
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAFUXicnVTBjpswEL3nK6z0EiSKSGnULKseIqKeknbTlaqNohwcM4AVYyNj2qbV/nttExIg2eyqPmCYN35vZjwDzQshFVqpVUXJfkA7n14kuJKClX37Ah9EpfrmYD54wCmgvwOk1w6TfSpFxeMQfQeiME+ZxhARTMgQDd9NP06nd5MherbuX0XcnDSL6lOlPhPPmODwSIDDCZtTqfmo4JgtaJopTYrzHQWuopp7pTyZ7vBo7Pku6jyco9oVxUaVa3PHuNQG1nNsnHODXSClqCQBk2NU7WB4gedYgaSYlSHaXIA2Q0hwxdTy6KcTjGmSVCX0EvQ9fxK4yPfGgW+2D+M7s32atPNs1rZjOePnt29SZSKVuMgoiXAOEl+pD7FA2/WL1G3S8TuEaOL79+hPiMa+73cwJsR+pkzxe7Wu46ifPyj8CuYtdcxJJmTpJZSxEBVYQkuybkPbJC93TR337fhr8aXQlZ5JwC/p9+QLKQqQ6oD0Eaa/oCwhfroNr0+w4FbvKcr0hEBsL5dgxhbm8kdVEevd6Xuv3+r9UMuFvYvcNFG6TTxb9BltchuJa7f19v5KiyQVt6OHaqmR0yNmoNAm/u3GhxYhen+qypH7bGnL/EdkZpku8qRQJh4tbUryU/8ghAzikRl7PRKOa8fdsy3xWGACzg2OQ5fDELzG0TTv8z8YMHoY)