# How to change speed or sensitivity mouse cursor in Qt

Tags: qt, qml, mouseevent, mouse

I wanna change the sensitivity of the cursor in the Qt project e.g. `MouseArea`. I found `QMouseDevice` or `MouseDevice` (in QML) for the 3D environment, these have `sensitivity` property. But I could not find a smooth example for that.

I test [by using SPI_SETMOUSESPEED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813653/mouse-speed-not-changing-by-using-spi-setmousespeed), with Qt v5.14 and MSVCx64 2017 compiler. But cannot handle that. [This page of github](https://github.com/moonlight-stream/moonlight-qt/issues/128) has some suggestions and I can't solve my prob.

Comment: You have a good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542807/how-to-rotate-a-3d-cube-in-qml